# Dart: a closure study

Tags: dart, closures

This snippet is of no practical significance. I've been just getting used to the closure idea.

```
var cls = () {
  var x = 5;
  return {
    'x': x,
    'inc': () {x++;},
  };
} ();

void main() {
  print(cls['x']);
  print(cls['inc']);
  cls['inc']();
  print(cls['x']);
}
```

DartPad output:

```
5
Closure '_closure'
5
Error compiling to JavaScript:
main.dart:18:13:
Error: The method 'call' isn't defined for the class 'dart.core::Object'.
```

The desired output would have been something like

```
5
6
```

What'd be the cleanest approach to this kind of exercise?

UPD:

The working example, courtesy of **Günter Zöchbauer**:

```
var cls = () {
  var x = 5;
  var map = <String, dynamic>{
    'x': x,
  };
  map['inc'] = () {map['x']++;};
  return map;
} ();

void main() {
  print(cls['x']);
  print(cls['inc']);
  cls['inc']();
  print(cls['x']);
}
```

DartPad output:

```
5
Closure '_closure'
6
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to declare the 'x' entry as a Function.

In your code, you set 'x' to the value of the 'x' variable (5) when you return the map. The value will always be 5 and will not update.

```
var cls = () {
  var x = 5;
  return {
    'x': () => x,
    'inc': () {x++;},
  };
}();

void main() {
  print(cls['x']()); // 5
  print(cls['x']); // Closure: () => int
  print(cls['inc']); // Closure: () => Null
  cls['inc']();
  print(cls['x']()); // 6
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var x = 5;
var cls = () {
  return {
    'x': x,
    'inc': () {x++;},
  };
} ();
```

You would need to move out the variable declaration, otherwise you'd re-declare and re-initialize it to `5` at every call.

**update**

```
var cls = () {
  var x = 5;
  var map = {
    'x': x,
   // 'inc': () {map['val']++;}, // not possible to reference the `map` variable that is just declared here so we need to move this out
  };
  map['inc'] = () {map['x']++;};
} ();
```

Comment: It's a solution, of course, but I meant creating a 'class instance' and keep `x` as an 'instance variable', or 'property' inside the closure. Otherwise the study is pointless.

Comment: Just a hint. `{
    'x': x,
    'inc': () {x++;},
  }` is a `Map` in Dart, not an object like in JS/TS.

Comment: Thanks! This is the root of my trouble :) . So even the working version is not going to be a closure, right?

Comment: There are several closures. `cls` references a closure, `map['inc']` references a closure. They might just not yet do what you want ;-)

Comment: `A value of type '() → Null' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'int'.` Looks like it thinks that a new `Map` value must be of `int` type. Funny.

Comment: Not sure where that comes from. Perhaps type inference. Try `var map = <String,dynamic>{ ...`